# Functionapp's function not loaded

Tags: .net, azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

I am deploying a timer function in .Net6 isolated process.
I can run it in debug locally successfully, but when deployed through devops to azure I can't see any function, devops doesn't show any error, all I have is app Insights showing this :
[image]

[image]

any idea why he sees the function but won't load it?

Edit: devops pipelines :
Build:

```
pool:
  name: Windows
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet build'
  inputs:
    arguments: '--configuration Release'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet publish'
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: '**\Weekly10Bridge.csproj'
    arguments: '--no-build --configuration Release --output 
$(Build.BinariesDirectory)'
    zipAfterPublish: false
    modifyOutputPath: false

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: Weekly10Bridge'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: Weekly10Bridge
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

Release:
[image]

Config:
[image]

Comment: Make `Website Run from package` to 0 in Function App Configuration Menu in the Portal before deployment and after saving the configuration > deploy and check!

Comment: I tried, didn't change :/

Comment: added some screenshots, if anything else can be useful let me know

Comment: @HariKrishna just noticed website run from package was back to 1, apparently devops does it on his own during release

Comment: In the devops step under Additional Deployment Options you can change the Deployment Method.  I believe that affects the website run from package setting.

Comment: @XavSc, Any update on the issue resolution?

Comment: unfortunately no, if it came from code (even if it s very basic for now) App Insights would show me an exception like startup failing right? why is this happening ...

Comment: Try with this setting `scm-do-build-during-deployment: true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description it seems you use 'timer trigger' for the function app in your local. **Please kindly place solution and project in the same directory.**

Then push these generated Azure function app folders and files into Azure devops Repo for using.

[image]

Then I use your build definition to generate artifact like this:

by the way, you need to replace

```
pool:
  name: Windows
```

to something like this:

```
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
```

[image]

Then go to release, I notice here are two points maybe influence the result, please check whether you done them.

[image]

1.Please **choose and use service connection which in the same subscription and resource group with the function app in Azure portal**. If you don't have, create one.

2.in the package or folder blank, the system suggest value as '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.zip or $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.war.'
You need to modify it according to your project. In my sample, I could directly choose folder.
[image]
[image]

Then once the release runs successfully, you could see the functions in the corresponding function app. The function app should exist before the deployment in Azure portal.

Please kindly check the points mentioned above, thanks.

Comment: hello, thank you, yes I found the issue yesterday, it was indeed point (2 mentioned, It was pointing to the wrong folder ... that simple ... unfortunately logs didn't mention anything and it took me too long to notice. Thanks for your reply anyway

Comment: I am so glad that you have found the issue. Happy coding!